# Problems Accessing Video Files in Rails 3.2.6 Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html5-video

I am writing a Rails 3.2.6 application where I want to show live streaming HTML5 videos along with on-demand videos at some point.  I am using the Evolv software to create the live HTML5 video segments, then sends them using AFP to my Mac Mini server running the latest version of Lion Server.  A playlist is created where it will play the HTML5 video segments.  My plan is to show the previously recorded live video during the times where there is not a live broadcast.

In my video tag in other websites (non-Rails) I am able to access the playlist using the entire url path.  Just to get the formatting for my video page I added the following video tag in my Rails application.  The video segments play as expected when I reference the playlist which plays the HTML5 video segments.

```
<video autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay" width="480" height="320"
controls="controls" src="http://www.mywebaddress.com/Live-Segments/playlist.m3u8"  
</video>
```

I want to replicate this logic in my Rails application.  However I'm not sure how to do this.

I have read in the 3.2.6 API information that Rails will search for videos within /public/videos.  I have created a live-segments (not capitalized) folder in my public/videos folder which contains the same playlist and HTML5 video segments that played fine when I reference the playlist from the other website.

I have tried the following examples using the HTML5 code but none of them find the video playlist.  It does show the video player with the poster.

```
<video autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay" width="480" height="320"
controls="controls" src="public/videos/live-segments/playlist.m3u8"  
</video>

<video autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay" width="480" height="320"
controls="controls" src="live-segments/playlist.m3u8"  
</video>
```

I have tried the following Ruby versions of the video tag.  It shows nothing at all.

```
<% video_tag("live-segments/playlist.m3u8", :controls => true, :autobuffer => true, :autoplay => true, :size => "480x320") %>

<% video_tag("/public/videos/live-segments/playlist.m3u8", :controls => true, :autobuffer => true, :autoplay => true, :size => "480x320") %>
```

I hope that there is a simple fix for this.  Hopefully I am not attempting to do something that is not supported in Rails.  Most of the posts I have found online have no responses.  The ones that had responses did not relate to the task I am trying to accomplish from what little I understand about including videos in websites other than using YouTube widgets.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research I was able to get the html5 video tag working.  I changed my code to:

```
<video autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay" width="480" height="320" controls="controls" src="/videos/live-segments/playlist.m3u8"</video>
```

However I was not able to get the Ruby on Rails video tag to work.  I used the same syntax as I mentioned in my original question but changed to use /videos/live-segments/playlist.m3u8.  I still got nothing.  Not even the poster showed up.  The caption below is now the first line of that section.

I will use the HTML5 video tag at this point.